# MaxClients exceeded on Heroku

Tags: apache-2.2, heroku

Our Heroku app went down for a period of time yesterday.  The error message in our logs:

```
[error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

I checked the httpd.conf to see what the MaxClients setting was, and this is what I found:

```
MaxClients 1
```

[The commit that added these directives](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/commit/cada9ca73ebda608bb148cf03fa5057a6e3966d9) is on Heroku's Github.  Does there appear to be a rationale for a MaxClients setting of 1, or is it simply arbitrary?  Are there any considerations I should make when increasing it?

Comment: How did you change this parameter sir?

Comment: You fork the [Heroku PHP Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) and edit the conf/httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku [dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos-and-requests) are designed to be a single unit of computation.  For comparison:

> A single-threaded, non-concurrent framework like Rails can process one request at a time.

Setting `MaxClients 1` is simply telling your PHP dyno to only handle its one request at a time.  Since the dyno is actually capable of handling many more requests that that, MaxClients can and should be raised to a number much larger, such as 256.

Comment: 256 is much too large. A Heroku dyno only has 512MB of memory. Each process probably uses 64MB, depending on what the `memory_limit` is in PHP.ini. So you should take 512 / 64 = 8 and set `MaxClients` and `ServerLimit` to that. Otherwise you run the risk of too many requests flooding the server and it spawning too many processes, possibly thrashing the disk or crashing. You can usually over-subscribe 20% because most requests don't take up all it's allocated RAM, so 10 is a good number.

Answer (score 1):

Here explaint mean MaxClients: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients

Try increase parameter about 250 and retry

Comment: I understand MaxClients is too low.  I'm trying to understand the why - why is the default setting 1, and what implications does that entail for changing it?

Comment: You'll have to ask whoever checked in the code. And the implications is that the server will only handle one simultaneous connection, which is very close to pointless.